# In Blue Wallet 6.0.2 for iOS, pressing on Bump Fee causes an infinite wait. Any idea why?

Tags: child-pays-for-parent, bluewallet

Think there might be a bug in Blue Wallet, I imported the said wallet to BlockChain.com iOS App, but the unconfirmed transaction was not even shown there.
In short, how can I CPFP my transaction now?

Comment: I don't know how to use BlueWallet but https://www.reddit.com/r/bluewallet/ may be of better help (at least compared to me).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. I concluded that when it worked correctly on a different transaction.